# How do I insert QTabBar in Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-designer

This might very well be very stupid question, but I can not find QTabBar in Qt Designer. There is QTabWidged in the "Containers" group, but it is not the same - I don't need different pages, I just need the tab bar.

(I am using 4.7.2 version of Qt Designer under KDE4 on debian.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no item in the designer that is a `QTabBar`, the only way you could accomplish this is by creating a plain `QWidget` and promoting it to a tabbar, but you will then have to set up the whole thing in code.

As for the pages you do realize that you can also promote the content widgets of a QTabWidget in designer to any subclass of QWidget, builtin or something that you created.

Comment: You mean promote in code or there is a way to do it in Designer? The reason I do not need pages is that there is going to be quite expansive widget on every "page" so I prefer to have only one instance of this and reload its contents on every tab click.

Comment: Information on [promoting in Qt Designer in 4.8](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html).

Answer (score 2):

In Qt Designer 4.8 you can add a Widget where you want the QTabBar to be, and then right-click and choose "Promote To ▸ QTabBar". (Note: "Promote To", not "Morph Into")